# CSS wrap image or "center float"

Tags: css

I am using the following code to display a list of images and apply a drop shadow effect to each image. The images may vary in orientation but will always be a maximum of 120px.

To get this to work I am having to float:left the "shadow" container. By adjusting the margins of the container and it's image, I am able to simulate a drop shadow. (http://img200.imageshack.us/i/withfloat.png/)

The downside of this approach is that the image then becomes left aligned. If I remove the float the .shadow background spans the full width of the li and does not wrap the image.
(see above url but "withoutfloat.png")

How can I get the shadow div to wrap the image and keep it centered within the li?

Css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li.box
    {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
        margin: 3px; 
        background: red;
        position: relative;
    }
    .wraptocenter
    {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
    }
    .wraptocenter *
    {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .shadow
    {
        background: blue;
        margin: 10px 0 0 10px !important;
        margin: 10px 0 0 5px; 

    }
    .shadow img
    {
        margin: -4px 6px 6px -4px;
    }
</style>
```

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="box">
        <div class="wraptocenter">
            <span>
                <div class="shadow">
                    <img src="Handler.ashx?id=936&size=103" />
                </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Taken from the FAQ: "Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is "designer", ask on Doctype."

Comment: @halfdan: That apparently is meant for people with an open Photoshop beside their browser. Positioning with CSS however can have the same intricacies as matrix management in FORTRAN, so relax.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float but add `overflow:auto` to the containing element.  That will make the non-floating element contain its inner floating elements the way you expect.

Comment: @Dave - I removed the float that I had on div.shadow and added overflow:auto. However, this did not appear to have any effect. The div.shadow container still fails to wrap the image. 

If you were referring to removing the float on the li element, this is required to render the list of images horizontally.